# Conflict between savepoint and commit

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a code block that takes some time to finish and I've created a progress variable on a table that the process will update so the end user can know how much is left to complete.

The thing is that the code block is treated as an atomic transaction so the progress variable value will only show 0% or 100%, unless I use the `commit` statement, which will remove a savepoint declared at a previous point on the block, and if an exception occurs it wont be recognized as valid.

The code is something like this:

```
begin
    /*do some stuff*/
    savepoint p_savepoint;
    for q in (somequery) loop /*Really long loop*/
            /*Do some other stuff*/
            update t_sys_state set p1_progress = percentage
            where user_id = 'theuserid';
            commit; /*This commit make the real progress value available*/
    end loop;
    exception
            when others then
                    rollback to p_savepoint; /*This savepoint is not recognized because of the previous commit*/
                    raise;
end;
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you just want to show the progress of your loop you might want to consider using `dbms_application_info` instead which lets you put that information into `v$session_longops`, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154203/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to update your progress in an autonomous transaction.  This is one of very, very few situations where using an autonomous transaction makes sense.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_progress( p_user IN varchar2,
                                          p_percentage IN number )
AS
  PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
  UPDATE t_sys_state 
     SET p1_progress  = p_percentage
   WHERE user_id      = p_user;
  commit;
END;
```

and then

```
begin
    /*do some stuff*/
    savepoint p_savepoint;
    for q in (somequery) loop /*Really long loop*/
            /*Do some other stuff*/
            log_progress( 'theuserid', percentage );
    end loop;
    exception
            when others then
                    rollback to p_savepoint; /*This savepoint is not recognized because of the previous commit*/
                    raise;
end;
```